# Adding button column to DataGridView but it won't show

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm adding a button column to my databound datagridview. The column gets created, and the button is clickable, but it doesn't really show. Its kinda hard to explain so I'm posting a screenshot below.

Here's the code

```
        private void LoadDataGridView()
        {
            dgvClients.DataSource = null;
            dgvClients.DataSource = Clients;

            DataGridViewButtonColumn btnDelete = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            btnDelete.Name = "btnDelete";
            btnDelete.Text = "Delete";
            btnDelete.HeaderText = "Delete";
            dgvClients.Columns.Add(btnDelete);

            //set column sizes. Total width of dgv w/o scrollbar is 544
            dgvClients.Columns[0].Width = 100;
            dgvClients.Columns[1].Width = 344;
            dgvClients.Columns[2].Width = 100;
            dgvClients.Columns[3].Width = 100;


            dgvClients.Show();
            dgvClients.ClearSelection();
        }
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do this when you define the button's properties.

```
btnDelete.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```